# Transfer/Copy files from one iPad app to another iPad app for Editing

Tags: objective-c, ipad, filesystems

I am wondering if there is a way in objective c to have my iPad app copy a file in it's documents folder to another app's documents folder and have that app open the file for editing and finally copy the file back to my documents folder. Or better yet, can I have another app open a file from my documents folder, edit the file, and save it back to my documents folder?

So far I know I can have another app open a file in my documents folder but the app that I'm handing the document off to seems to be making a local copy and editing the copy. I also know that each app's document folder is a shared folder that users can drag and drop stuff from itunes but I'm not sure if the same can be done in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though a sandbox exists, I found a way to work around it (it's a trick being used by other File Manager apps like GoAruna). I would first register my app as an app that can open the type of files that I plan to work with. Then I use the Open In functionality to have my users open up my apps local documents in the second app, an app like iAnnotate. Then, because my app is registered as an app that can open the current file type, I can instruct my users to use Open In from iAnnotate to move the modified document back to my app. Sorry but I could not accept "no" as an answer. If anyone is interested in this approach, go [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure what you are trying to do is impossible.  iOS applications are "sandboxed" which means that each app has its own documents directory.  No application has access to the file system outside its own "sandbox" i.e. outside its own local documents directory.

For more on the iOS application sandbox, [Read here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW44)

Answer (score 0):

If your iPad is jail broken, try this:

On the app iFile, type in the document name in the search box located at the top. Once you find the document, click on it and options would be showed to you. From here you can choose the app you want to open the file with.

Hope this helps.